# using "as" or "according to" which word

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Do I have to use "*according to*" or "*as*" in following sentences.

> 1. Someone applied for job who doesnt smoke **as** written his cv.
> 2. Someone applied for job who doesnt smoke **according to** information in his cv.

Which sentence more formal?

Comment: I think there is a problem with both sentences and it isn't choice between "as" or "according to". What are you actually trying to say? Is it that someone who applied for a job doesn't smoke and that fact is stated on his CV?

Comment: I edited, Yes that fact is stated on his cv.  someone who don't smoke. because he wrote that he doesn't smoke in his cv.

Comment: Whichever choice you choose, consider fronting it or using a comma, e.g., "He doesn't smoke, as (is) written in his CV." "He doesn't smoke, according to (the information in) his CV." Without a comma, it could be understood as "We're disappointed that he doesn't smoke, because we expected him to be a smoker. His CV says he is one!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would re-phrase it completely. Something like this would make more sense (I think):

*The applicant doesn't smoke according to information on his CV.*

or

*[The applicant's name] doesn't smoke according to information on his CV.*